# Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6. Searchbox overflows container on navbar collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new Bootstrap 4, so there might be lots of mistakes here.

I want to create a responsive navbar which collapses my 4 menu buttons but still keeping the search bar to its right. I'm not sure yet how to deal with the display of the buttons after expanding, but my goal for now is to keep the search bar to the right with a correct width.

When the screen gets "small", the nav-toggle button shows up, collapsing the menu buttons. That's cool. But the search bar just grows off the container its in. How do I keep it within the container?

I appreciate any suggestions and improvements :)

```css
nav {
  background: brown;
}

nav .container {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>My Site</title>
</head>

<body>



  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm">

    <div class="container" style="width:1400px">


      <div class="d-inline-block">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      </div>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="fa fa-home"> Home</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="fa fa-music"> Music</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="fa fa-info"> About</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="fa fa-address-card"> Contact Us</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <form class="d-inline-block w-100" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by artist or album name">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
        </div>
      </form>



    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

EDIT: I tweaked around a little and got the following result -> https://jsfiddle.net/Taliesin84/qL35nejo/

My current objective is to prevent the Search bar from wrapping bellow the collapsed buttons when the size gets too small. 
I also need to make the Search Bar wider in larger screen sizes, but that's secondary for now. Any new ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From an example contained in Bootstrap 4's github repo:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Once the menu items are collapsed, the search box gets wrapped to a line below :(